# Не получается добавить внешний ключ

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не добавляются ключи в таблице `Products`.
Пишет:

> указывает на недопустимый столбец

```
create table Categories(
  id int not null  identity(1,1) primary key,
  CategoryName nvarchar(20) unique,
  Description nvarchar(50)
)

create table Suppliers(
  id int not null primary key  identity(1,1),
  SupplierName nvarchar(15) unique,
  Address  nvarchar(20),
  City nvarchar(20),
  Country nvarchar(20)
)
create table Products(
  id int not null primary key  identity(1,1),
  ProductName nvarchar(15), 
  FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID) REFERENCES Suppliers(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES Categories(id),
  Unit nvarchar(20),
  Price money
)
```

Comment: Ну так сами-то поля где? FK не создаёт поле, а только устанавливает связь уже созданного поля с внешним...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
  ProductName nvarchar(15),
  SupplierID int NOT NULL,
  CategoryID int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID) REFERENCES Suppliers (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES Categories (id),
  Unit nvarchar(20),
  Price money
)
```

Comment: Сделайте ваш ответ более качественным, дополните его информацией, почему вы так сделали и ссылками на справочные источники.